# Proof for $\left \langle a^k \right \rangle=\left \langle a^{\gcd(n,k)} \right \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Theorem: $\left \langle a^k \right \rangle=\left \langle a^{\gcd(n,k)} \right \rangle$
>
> Let $a$ be an element of order n in a group and let $k$ be a positive integer. Then $\left \langle a^k \right \rangle=\left \langle a^{\gcd\left ( n,k \right )} \right \rangle$ and $\left | a^k \right |=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$

The author provides the proof as follows(excerpt):

> Let $d=\gcd(n,k)$ and let $k=dr$. Since $a^k=(a^d)^r$, we have by closure that $\left \langle a^k \right \rangle\sqsubseteq \left \langle a^d \right \rangle$

At this point I've failed to understand why the closure holds. How does $a^k=(a^d)^r$ shows closure?

Continuing,

> By the GCD theorem, there are integers $s$ and $t$ such that $d=ns+kt$. So, $a^d =a^{ns+kt} = a^{ns}a^{kt} = (a^n)^s (a^k)^t =e(a^k)^t=(a^k)^t \in\left \langle a^k \right \rangle.$
>
> This proves $\left \langle a^{d} \right \rangle\sqsubseteq \left \langle a^{k}\right \rangle$

Alright.
$\left \langle a^{k}\right \rangle=\left \{ a^{0k}=e,a^{1k},a^{2k},\cdot \cdot \cdot ,a^{\left ( n-1 \right )k} \right \}$
and $\left ( a^{k} \right )^{t}=\left \{ a^{\left ( 0k \right )t},a^{\left ( 1k \right )t},\cdot \cdot \cdot ,a^{\left ( n-1 \right )kt} \right \}$ so indeed, $\left ( a^{k} \right )^{t}\in\left \langle a^{k} \right \rangle \exists t \in\mathbb{Z}$

But again, how does this leads to closure? Having trouble seeing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

We're using two basic facts:

(i) In any ring, $x \mid y \iff y \in \langle x \rangle$;

(ii) $y \in \langle x \rangle \iff \langle y \rangle \subseteq \langle x \rangle$.

With this in mind, we have that $a^k = (a^d)^r \implies a^k \in \langle a^d\rangle \implies \langle a^k\rangle \subseteq \langle a^d\rangle$. On the other hand, we have $a^d = (a^k)^t \implies a^d \in \langle a^k\rangle \implies \langle a^d\rangle \subseteq \langle a^k \rangle$. So we conclude that $\langle a^d\rangle = \langle a^k \rangle$.

Comment: What does the notation used in x | y means?

Comment: "x divides y" ${}{}$